# Flutter gestureDetector not work as button

Tags: flutter, gesturedetector

I use `TextButton()` to trigger a method from the logical class. It work well and actually trigger that method. But that button contain splash effect and i don't want this splash.

Here is my code with `TextButton()`

```
TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  internetConnectionWatcher.initialConnectivity();
                },
                child: Column(
                  children: const [
                    Text('Please try again'),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Icon(Icons.refresh),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```

---

So I changed `TextButton()` with `GestureDetector()`, button's `onPressed:` callback also change to gestureDetector's `onTap:`. I also add `behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,` in `GestureDetector()` Widget.

Here is my code with `GestureDetector()`

```
GestureDetector(
                behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                onTap: () => internetConnectionWatcher.initialConnectivity(),
                child: SizedBox(
                  child: Column(
                    children: const [
                      Text('Please try again'),
                      SizedBox(
                        height: 10,
                      ),
                      Icon(Icons.refresh),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

---

This is the method that from logic class for internet connectivity checking.

```
void initialConnectivity() async {

    try {
      connectionStatus = await _connectivity.checkConnectivity();
      if (connectionStatus == ConnectivityResult.none) {
        _isInternetController.sink.add(false);
      } else {
        var result = await ConnectivityUtil.pingSucced();
        if (result) {
          _isInternetController.sink.add(true);

        } else {
          _isInternetController.sink.add(false);
        }
      }
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      developer.log(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

**Problem**

But after changing, can't trigger a method from logical class and get so many error. Why this happen? What is real problem?

**Edit:**  `Inkwell()` also work well as `TextButton()`. Only `GestureDetector()` got that problem.

**Edit: 2nd time**
When I debug the stream with `print()`. The `Stream` got result only (when got `true` got to next page) `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback` not work. But if I add `setState((){})`, Go to next page with `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`
Here is my stream listening method.

```
internetConnectionWatcher.isInternetStream.listen(
      (event) {
        print('WHT $event');
        if (event) {
          WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
            (_) => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, loginRoute),
          );
          setState(() {

          });
        }
      },
    );
```

In last scenario, I want to know is why `setState((){})` need to work `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`?

Comment: Can you add what errors you are getting?

Comment: Yep... I edit and add for my question.

Answer (score 0):

I found problem. Inside build method `listen()` the stream, that result come from after trigger the method from logical class by `GestureDetector()`.
Code inside `listen()` I used

```
internetConnectionWatcher.isInternetStream.listen(
      (event) {
        print('WHT $event');
        if (event) {

          // WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
          //  (_) => Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, loginRoute),
          // );
          ///// That work well after change this

          Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, loginRoute);
        }
      },
    );
```

That is the problem, when I removed `WidgetBinding` and imply route that work well.
But I want to know what is the different `GestureDetector()` and other?